# Changing integer part of variable in while loop jQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, integer

So I have a variable named c[insert integer here]_bool.
The list of variables are:

```
        c1_bool =                                           false,
        c2_bool =                                           false,
        c3_bool =                                           false,
        c4_bool =                                           false,
        c5_bool =                                           false,
        c6_bool =                                           false,
        c7_bool =                                           false,
        c8_bool =                                           false,
```

I want to loop through these variables, and add another variable, like:

```
var iC = 1;

while( iC < 9 ){
 if( c[here comes iC]_bool ){
  //insert code
 } else {}
 iC ++;
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is possible through the use of `eval()`, that is a hack and should not be used.

A better approach would be to set the flags as properties of an object. You can then use bracket notation to concatenate the name of the property. Try this:

```
var flags = {
    c1: false,
    c2: false,
    c3: false,
    c4: false,
    c5: false,
    c6: false,
    c7: false,
    c8: false
}

for (var i = 0; i <= Object.keys(flags).length; i++) {
    if (flags['c' + (i + 1)]) {
        // do something
    } else {}
}
```

Assuming there are no other properties in the object, you can just loop through it's keys:

```
for (var key in flags) {
    if (flags[key]) {
        console.log(key);
    } else {}
}
```

Comment: Or, frankly, an array.

Comment: You typed flags['c' + iC]. That should be, in this case, flags['c' + iC + '_bool'] right?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder true, although I didn't change the data structure as I assumed there was a reason the OP is using an object; other unmentioned properties perhaps.

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen: Not with Rory's object, no, it leaves off the `_bool` part of the name. (If you include it, then yes, you'll want to add it back.)

Comment: @MaartenWolfsen I removed the `_bool` from the property names as typed variable names are largely redundant.

Comment: oh, yeah, I see. Well, it seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: By the way, why is eval() not a good solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-the-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea